# Android - Displaying decimal as formatted fraction (and vice versa)

Tags: android, decimal, fractions

In Java, assuming I have a `double` variable called `decimal` with the assigned value of `0.333`, how would I display this as a "proper", formatted fraction - with the numerator over the denominator separated with a straight line (as opposed to simply displaying `1/3`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: One of the solutions is to use Apache Commons Mathematics Library, namely the [Fractions](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html) package. Referencing the doc:

> A fraction number, can be built from two integer arguments representing numerator and denominator or from a double which will be approximated:

```
Fraction f = new Fraction(1, 3); // 1 / 3
Fraction g = new Fraction(0.25); // 1 / 4
```

So all you need to do after that is to display it, a simple way of doing that is using android.text.Html method [fromHtml(String source, int flags)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) with superscript and subscript tags. Note that this was added in API level 24 and changed **fromHtml(String source)**.